# Does the change of the leaf_size parameter affect memory usage of sklearn.cluster.dbscan?

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I managed to run out of memory while conducting a sklearn.cluster.dbscan clustering on a large data set (sklearn.**version** 1.1.2)

here is an example call

```
dbscan(xy, eps=40, min_samples=10, algorithm='kd_tree', leaf_size=100)
```

where `xy` is a numpy array of shape (180538, 2). The original data has shape (579990, 2).

I've tried to set the algorithm explicitly ('ball_tree' and 'kd_tree'), which didn't make any difference.

I also varied the 'leaf_size' parameter between 3 and 500, which does not seem to have any affect on the performance whatsoever.

Is this to be expected or is there a problem?

Comment: To run dbscan as mention with 180000 data points requires about 20GB RAM. I'm not sure about the exact value

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) states:

> The `leaf_size` can affect the speed of the construction and query, as
> well as the memory required to store the tree.

When you dig a little bit deeper, for `BallTree`:

> The amount of memory needed to store the tree scales as approximately `n_samples / leaf_size`.

So a larger `leaf_size` is supposed to reduce your memory consumption. The same applies to `KDTree`.

What you can try is to have an even larger `leaf_size` though this will take more compute time.

Hope this helps,

Mai65

Comment: My machine has 64GB RAM.